# Rows not sortable when clicking on column header

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to fix a problem with sorting columns so that when I click on them, my values sort in ascending or descending order.
I can't locate the error. Currently if I click on it, nothing happens, it doesn't order them for me

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tabella Interattiva</title>
    
<style>
    .....
</style>

<script>
function toggleView() {
    var tableView = document.getElementById("tableView");
    var gridView = document.getElementById("gridView");
    var toggleButton = document.getElementById("toggleButton");
    var tableContainer = document.querySelector(".table-container");

    if (tableView.style.display === "none") {
        tableView.style.display = "block";
        gridView.style.display = "none";
        toggleButton.textContent = "Visualizza come griglia";
        tableContainer.classList.remove("grid-mode");
    } else {
        tableView.style.display = "none";
        gridView.style.display = "flex";
        toggleButton.textContent = "Visualizza come tabella";
        tableContainer.classList.add("grid-mode");
    }
}

function sortTable(columnHeader, column) {
    var table = document.getElementById("tableView");
    var rows = Array.from(table.getElementsByTagName("tr"));
    var switching = true;
    var dir = 1;

    if (columnHeader.classList.contains("asc")) {
        columnHeader.classList.remove("asc");
        columnHeader.classList.add("desc");
        dir = -1;
    } else if (columnHeader.classList.contains("desc")) {
        columnHeader.classList.remove("desc");
        columnHeader.classList.add("asc");
    } else {
        columnHeader.classList.add("asc");
    }

    var headerColumns = Array.from(table.getElementsByClassName("table-header")[0].getElementsByTagName("th"));
    headerColumns.forEach(function (col) {
        if (col !== columnHeader) {
            col.classList.remove("asc", "desc");
        }
    });

    if (table.classList.contains("grid-mode")) {
        var gridItems = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("grid-item"));
        sortGridItems(gridItems);
    } else {
        sortTableRows(rows, column, columnHeader.classList.contains("asc") ? "asc" : "desc");
    }
}

function sortTableRows(rows, column, order) {
    var switching = true;
    var dir = order === "asc" ? 1 : -1;

    while (switching) {
        switching = false;
        for (var i = 1; i < rows.length - 1; i++) {
            var x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[column].textContent;
            var y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("td")[column].textContent;
            if (dir * x.toLowerCase() > dir * y.toLowerCase()) {
                rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
                switching = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

function sortGridItems(items) {
    var sortedItems = Array.prototype.slice.call(items).sort(function (a, b) {
        var sortOrderA = parseInt(a.getAttribute("data-sort-order"));
        var sortOrderB = parseInt(b.getAttribute("data-sort-order"));
        return sortOrderA - sortOrderB;
    });

    var gridView = document.getElementById("gridView");
    while (gridView.firstChild) {
        gridView.removeChild(gridView.firstChild);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < sortedItems.length; i++) {
        gridView.appendChild(sortedItems[i]);
    }
}

</script>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>Tabella Interattiva</h1>
    <div class="table-container grid-mode">
    <div class="centered-form">
        <form method="POST" action="/">
            <input type="text" name="search_term" placeholder="Filtro per artista, brano o genere">
            <button type="submit">Cerca</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    
    <div class="table-container">
        <div style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
            <button id="toggleButton" class="toggle-button" type="button" onclick="toggleView()">Visualizza come griglia</button>
        </div>
        <table id="tableView">
            <thead>
                <tr class="table-header">
                   
                    
                    <th onclick="sortTable(this, 0)" class="{% if sort_column == 'artist' %}{{ sort_order }}{% endif %}">Artista</th>
                    <th onclick="sortTable(this, 1)" class="{% if sort_column == 'name' %}{{ sort_order }}{% endif %}">Brano</th>
                    <th onclick="sortTable(this, 2)" class="{% if sort_column == 'genres' %}{{ sort_order }}{% endif %}">Generi</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for track in tracks %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ track.artist }}</td>
                    <td>{{ track.name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ track.genres }}</td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <div id="gridView" class="grid-view">
            <div class="grid-column">
                {% for track in tracks %}
                <div class="grid-item" data-sort-order="{{ loop.index }}">
                    <img src="{{ track.image_url }}" alt="Locandina">
                    <div class="grid-item-content">
                        <p><strong>Artista: {{ track.artist }}</strong></p>
                        <p><strong>Brano: {{ track.name }}</strong></p>
                        <div class="partner-item">
                            <h4>Partner:</h4>
                            <p>Cerca informazioni su Wikipedia, ad esempio</p>
                            <a href="https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/{{ track.name }}" target="_blank">
                                <button class="wikipedia-button">Cerca su Wikipedia</button>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <p>Generi: {{ track.genres }}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The backend is in flask, a simple python code, this is the most relevant part

```
def sort_tracks(tracks, column, order):
    if column == 'artist':
        tracks.sort(key=lambda x: x['artist'], reverse=(order == 'desc'))
    elif column == 'name':
        tracks.sort(key=lambda x: x['name'], reverse=(order == 'desc'))
    elif column == 'genres':
        tracks.sort(key=lambda x: x['genres'], reverse=(order == 'desc'))

    return tracks

def get_liked_tracks():
    liked_tracks = []

    # Recupera gli ultimi 5 brani a cui hai messo "Mi piace"
    results = sp.current_user_saved_tracks(limit=10)

    for item in results['items']:
        track = item['track']
        artists = [artist['name'] for artist in track['artists']]

        # Recupera i generi per ogni artista
        genres = []
        for artist in track['artists']:
            artist_info = sp.artist(artist['id'])
            genres.extend(artist_info['genres'])

        liked_tracks.append({
            'artist': ', '.join(artists),
            'name': track['name'],
            'genres': ', '.join(genres),
            'image_url': track['album']['images'][0]['url']  # URL dell'immagine della locandina
        })

    return liked_tracks

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    search_term = request.form.get('search_term', '')
    tracks = get_liked_tracks()
    if search_term:
        tracks = filter_tracks(tracks, search_term)

    sort_column = request.args.get('sort_column', session.get('sort_column'))
    sort_order = request.args.get('sort_order', session.get('sort_order'))

    if sort_column is not None and sort_order is not None:
        tracks = sort_tracks(tracks, sort_column, sort_order)
        session['sort_column'] = sort_column
        session['sort_order'] = sort_order

    return render_template('index.html', tracks=tracks, sort_column=sort_column, sort_order=sort_order)

def filter_tracks(tracks, search_term):
    if not search_term:
        return tracks

    filtered_tracks = []
    for track in tracks:
        if (
            search_term.lower() in track['artist'].lower()
            or search_term.lower() in track['name'].lower()
            or search_term.lower() in track['genres'].lower()
        ):
            filtered_tracks.append(track)

    return filtered_tracks
```

Comment: Please click [edit], then `[<>]` stacksnippet and produce a [mcve] with RENDERED HTML and relevant script/frameworks/CSS and remove the python/flask since it is irrelevant  to the JavaScript issue you have

Comment: @mplungjan i can't add a rendered html because data are taken using spotify API

Comment: Load a small example, right-click, click inspect, remove irrelevant HTML. Shorten to 3 examples